# What does the angle bracket syntax mean after calling function findViewById in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, interface, findviewbyid

Kotlin newbie here;

I'm working my way through a tutorial, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/floating-action-button

I see in a the basic activity sample code a `findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab)`, where the  `<FloatingActionButton>` part is throwing me off.

```
 findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab).setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, getString(R.string.MySnackBar), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
```

I'm confused because in other sample code, i see
`val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.roll_button)`

Is the first `findViewById<FloatingActionButton>`an interface(?) And if so, why does it need one, when the second one works by passing it in a button as is?

Am I misunderstanding syntax, or missing a concept perhaps?

I'm sure I'm missing some piece of this puzzle, but don't see it.

Thanks preemptively for any help or doc you can refer me to that explains it!

Comment: Read about generic functions and generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById()` needs to be told what type of view to expect. You can do this in one of two ways:

- By explicitly specifying the type of the variable

```
val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
```

- By passing a type argument to `findViewById()`

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
```

You can of course combine the two, but only one is necessary.

Personally, I prefer the first option because it avoids the inferring of [platform types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#null-safety-and-platform-types).

Comment: Thank you kindly sir, that is a great explanation!

Comment: That answered my question, but small follow up, why does it require defining what it expects as output, wouldn't that be part of the function declaration/signature where it's made and not where I'm calling it?

I think there is probably a more advanced or modern programming concept I just am not familiar with.
Thanks again!

Comment: The function declaration looks like this: `public final <T extends View> T findViewById(int id) {`. The important part is `<T extends View> T`. In Java, you always provide this information in the variable declaration (e.g., `Button button = findViewById(...)`), but in kotlin you sometimes rely on type inference, and then there's nothing to tell the compiler what to use for `T`.

Comment: Thanks again! Mych appreciated!